# Using jQuery to fade in inline-table elements

Tags: jquery

I want to fade in three divs, one after the other. They need to be set to display:inline-table for formatting. I want each div to push the others aside as it fades in, eventually squeezing three in line.

I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $("#uno").delay(600).fadeIn(300);
  $("#dos").delay(1200).fadeIn(300);
  $("#tres").delay(1800).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Which faded in one by one perfectly, but set the display to block and killed formatting.

So I tried this (With all three divs set to display:none in the stylesheet):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#uno") .css("display", "inline-table");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#dos") .css("display", "inline-table");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#tres") .css("display", "inline-table");
  }, 3000);
});
```

But of course no fade.

So I tried to do both:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#uno") .css({
      opacity: 0,
      display: 'inline-table'     
    }).animate({opacity:1},600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#dos") .css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-table'     
      }).animate({opacity:1},600);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#tres") .css({
          opacity: 0,
          display: 'inline-table'     
        }).animate({opacity:1},600);
      });
```

Which doesn't work at all :/

HTML:

```
<div class="skillgrp">
     <div class="skill" id="uno" >    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p> </div>
       <div class="skill" id="dos" >      <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p>  </div>
         <div class="skill" id="tres" >    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p>   </div>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```css
#uno, #dos, #tres {
  display: none;
}
.skill {
  background-color: #8c7aae;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML as well, along with CSS in a [mcve]? Use Stack Snippets.

Comment: It looks like your code is not complete as well. The JavaScript doesn't make any sense. It's incomplete.

Comment: The first line of the third code block got cut off, it's just above it

Comment: I saw the code above, even with that it's not complete dude. I asked for HTML as well.

Comment: Okay, what exactly I want from you is, press Ctrl + M. Then you will be shown something like HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Put the required code and it should be alright.

Comment: Just accepted the edit. I'm just fishing out the snippets for the HTML and CSS

Comment: Awesome. Waiting...

Comment: Added additional bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to push `div`s aside and fade in without losing `display: inline-table`, you might want to use the `width` property on `div`s, like so :-

**HTML**

```
<div id="dos"></div>
<div id="tres"></div>
<div id="uno"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-table;
    opacity: 0;
}
#uno { background-color: red; }
#dos { background-color: green; }
#tres { background-color: blue; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

    $("#uno").delay(600).animate({
        width: '100px',
        opacity:1
    },600);
    $("#dos").delay(1200).animate({
        width: '100px',
        opacity:1
    },600);
    $("#tres").delay(1800).animate({
        width: '100px',
        opacity:1
    },600);

});
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/cod3rguy/pen/oBNqKE

Comment: @Thomh No problem :)

Comment: @Thomh Quickly check my answer and give me your comments?

Comment: This answer came in 5 minutes before yours and met what I needed. Jobs a gooden

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#uno").css("display", "inline-table").animate({
  opacity:1,
  });
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#dos").css("display", "inline-table").animate({
  opacity:1,
  });
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#tres").css("display", "inline-table").animate({
  opacity:1,
  });
  }, 3000);
```

```css
#uno, #dos, #tres {
      display: none;
      opacity:0;
  }
.skill {
background-color: #8c7aae;
min-width: 350px;
max-width: 25%;
height: 250px;
margin: 20px 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skillgrp">
     <div class="skill" id="uno" >    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p> </div>
       <div class="skill" id="dos" >      <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p>  </div>
         <div class="skill" id="tres" >    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>    <p>dvgregggfgfgr </p>   </div>
         </div>
```

So, just syntax was problem. And set initial opacity to 0, on divs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forgot to add the timing function for the `setTimeout`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#uno").css({
      opacity: 0,
      display: 'inline-table'
    }).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#dos").css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-table'
      }).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 600);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#tres").css({
          opacity: 0,
          display: 'inline-table'
        }).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 600);
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#uno,
#dos,
#tres {
  display: none;
}
.skill {
  background-color: #8c7aae;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div class="skillgrp">
  <div class="skill" id="uno">
    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>
    <p>dvgregggfgfgr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill" id="dos">
    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>
    <p>dvgregggfgfgr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill" id="tres">
    <h2>wfcewfcef</h2>
    <p>dvgregggfgfgr</p>
  </div>
</div>
```